# Meaning of numbers after colon

Tags: r

```
planets <- c("Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune");
str(factor(planets))
```

This give me the answer that "Factor w/ 8 levels "Earth","Jupiter",..: 4 8 1 3 2 6 7 5"

I don't understand the meaning of the numbers after colon. Is it means that Earth is at the position of 4 in the factor? After reading several site, it say that it is internal level representations of factor, but what is the meaning of internal level representations of factor? It confuses me. I'm a beginner in R programming.

Comment: Factors are stored as integers. The integer codes correspond to ordered set of strings listed as the "levels". Have a look at the documentation or at this tutorial: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/factor_variables.htm

Comment: looks like the position in the container?  4 equates to earth, the 4th item in the solar system.  Its its index

Comment: @Frank has given the valid answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [the Quick-R tutorial](http://statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html):

> The factor stores the nominal values as a vector of integers in the range `[ 1... k ]` (where `k` is the number of unique values in the nominal variable), and an internal vector of character strings (the original values) mapped to these integers.

If you don't specify the levels for the factor, R will order the entries alphabetically, and will identify each level with an ascending list of integers.

In your example, the integer list shows the position that each entry has in your original vector; your vector is `Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune`. but the ordered vector is `Earth Jupiter Mars Mercury Neptune Saturn Uranus Venus`, so `Mercury` is in position 4, `Venus` in position 8, `Earth` in position 1, and so on.

If you want the factor to be ordered just as you entered it, you should do something like this:

```
factor(planets, levels=planets)
```

The output for `str(factor(planets, levels=planets))` is:

```
Factor w/ 8 levels "Mercury","Venus",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```